# Send parameters to a php file in different language

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, hindi

I am querying a php script using js with following func call:

```
$.post("http://localhost/abc/create.php",{
        name:data
    } ,function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Now this name parameter can be in any language, eg: english, hindi etc.. my code is working fine for english. But it is not working for hindi. When i am sending the request with adding name in the post parameter, the name is sent in a html encoded manner. Is there a way i can send my whole name properly and without any data loss.

Please suggest.. thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is. An example would be best

Comment: You should make sure that you are using proper UTF-8 encoding. On both sides. This is usually the reason for such problems.

Comment: there is no data loss if its encoded. Do you `urldecode` it on the serverside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the name parameter gets encoded to html? Can't you just use the html_entity_decode() function in PHP? Should work or any text in any language.